# Why i see many post requests in firebug console when i submit form via ajax in jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am using the jquery Form plugin to submit the form.
Everything is working correctly.

But when i turn on the firebug console and i hit submit buttom then i see 10 post requests with same data.

I even tried disabling the submit button but even then i see 10 post requests with same post data and response.

What is the problem

EDIT: this is what i am using

```
$(".myform").ajaxForm(options);     
            $('.myform').submit(function() { 
            $(this).ajaxSubmit(); 
                return false; 
            });
```

Comment: It's impossible to say without you showing some code...

Comment: I was really confused which part of code to post

Comment: whats in the options variable?

Comment: also this will submit the form every time you load the script. Is that the behavior you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When

```
$('.myform').submit(function() { 
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(); 
        return false; 
});
```

is called you immediately submit the form. For your application it might be enough to only have

```
$(".myform").ajaxForm();
```

or you might need to wrap

```
$('.myform').submit(function() { 
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(); 
        return false; 
});
```

in a function that is called when the submit button is pressed. I'm a little bit guessing here since I've only seen the limited code you've posted.

Comment: Thanks buddy , that was the mistake i was doing